# Calculate $f^{(50)}(2)$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+4x-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2+4x-1}}$$

---

$f^{(50)}(2)=?$

Methods I know for solving this type of tasks are Taylor series, but I don't know how to expand this function. I also know about Leibnitz rule, but first and second derivative are ugly and i can't find correlation between them. Anyone can give me hint or idea?

Comment: with the help of a PC we obtain $$\frac{12090617745023317361933735588365559337369785400390625}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Rewrite it as $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3 - (x-2)^2}}.$$ Do you know the binomial series?

Comment: Haha, thanks, but i need to solve it using only pencil and paper. This from 2012 exam task 1. https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/nastava/analiza/kolokviji/ma2-1112-kol1.pdf , so i didn't make it up

Comment: We didn't use binomial series in lectures, but isn't that $(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha}{n} x^n$ @Daniel can you solve it using binomial series

Comment: A binomial series expansion gives you the form in Robert Z's answer. Can you go on from there?

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(1 - \frac{(x-2)^2}{3}\right)^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\binom{-1/2}{k}\left(\frac{(x-2)^2}{3}\right)^k.$$
Hence
$$f^{(50)}(2)=-\frac{50!}{3^{25}\sqrt{3}}\binom{-1/2}{25}=\frac{50!}{2^{50}3^{25}\sqrt{3}}\binom{50}{25}=\frac{(50!/25!)^2}{2^{50}3^{25}\sqrt{3}}\\=\frac{12090617745023317361933735588365559337369785400390625}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$
which is Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's result.

P.S. Since $f(x+2)$ is an even function then $f^{(n)}(2)=0$ for any odd positive integer $n$.